# How to translate a blood type used in Eastern Europe?

Tags: hematology

What are the I-IV blood type descriptions shown below (commonly used in Eastern Europe), and how do you translate them into the ABO-system?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by translate?

Comment: @WYSIWYG: Convert it to the system used in the West: http://www.redcrossblood.org/learn-about-blood/blood-types

Comment: I still don't understand. Isn't it already clear from the image?

Comment: @WYSIWYG: What's this (I), (II), (III), etc. stuff? I guess that's what I'm asking.

Comment: I think this description is wrong. Blood type used to be described as AB-I, A-II, B-III and O-IV plus Rh Positive or Negative.

Comment: You should provide references for your answers. The article linked to in my answer describes two numerical systems: one created by Jansky (which is what is shown in the question and referred to in my answer) and one created by Moss (which is what you are describing).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is a direct correlation between the ABO blood groups and the Roman numerals.

```
 O: I

 A: II

 B: III

AB: IV
```

This numeric system was pioneered by Jan Jansky of Czechoslovakia in the early 20th century. Apparently it is still used in some former Soviet states.

[Erb IH. 1940. Blood Group Classification (A Plea for Uniformity). Can Med Assoc J 42(5):418-421.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC537907/?page=1)

Comment: I can't upvote it (not enough rep.) But thanks for the info!

Comment: @MikeF you should be able to accept it by clicking the check mark.

Comment: What would O+ in the US be in the UK?